# Vaadin Maven Multimodule application with vaadin 23

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, vaadin14, vaadin23

Is there any maven archetype for vaadin 23 multimodule application like we have for vaadin 8 or any online way to create vaadin maven multimodule web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a minimal example here: https://github.com/vaadin/multi-module-example.